# Двоеточие или тиpе, если есть и перечисление, и пояснение .

Tags: пунктуация, тире-или-двоеточие

Скажите, какой знак следует ставить (: или -), когда идет перечисление местонахождений какого-нибудь предмета, а далее более подробное разъяснение этого местонахождения. Например:
Лисицу можно найти в следующих местах:
1. Африка: на севере страны
2. Китай: на юге страны
Или же я должен ставить здесь тире:
1. Африка - на севере страны
2. Китай - на юге страны

Answer (score 2):

Наверно, тире. Но точно не двоеточие. (Имел в виду под пунктами, а после обобщающего слова, конечно, двоеточие.)

Comment: Кто это мне -1 поставил, да ещё прямо перед тем, как я поправил ответ?!

Comment: Матвей, зачем мне запятые лишние вставляете?

Comment: откатывайте свои ответы, если вам не нравится их редактирование. если читаете правку вандальной, жалуйтесь модератору.  К сожалению, это все, чем могу помочь. Вступать в полемику с автором такой правки бесполезно.

Comment: Спасибо за совет. А если я ответ удалю, мне -1 не спишется, конечно? Мне кажется это несправедливым. Плюсы, наверное, действительно тут не за что ставить, но зачем минус было ставить, непонятно. :( Так и вернулся начальный балл.

Comment: "если читаете правку вандальной" Как раз Б он мне по делу поправил - опечатка была, так что не полностью вандальная она.

Comment: Не знаю, может и спишется. давно перестал на такую ерунду внимания обращать. Нет, а данном случае не считаю правку совсем уж неправильной,.  Не надо удалять ответ, просто сохраните то, что считаете правильным, а остальное восстанавливайте.  Смысл моей рекомендации в том, что не надо это выяснять таким образом. Минусы ставили и будут ставить просто так, меньше единицы все равно не бывает. А вот с правкой тут действительно обидно бывает. Но это надо сносить стойко.

Comment: Спасибо за поддержку, behemothus! :) Единственное, я не понял, что восстанавливать, но может это и не важно.

Comment: Э... Граммар-наци скажут, что писать надо "Наверно — тире", а использовать не наверно, а точно

Answer (score 1):

> Лисицу можно найти в следующих местах: в Африке (на севере страны), в Китае (на юге).

Я приветствую такое оформление. Здесь мы имеем однородные члены, перед которыми стоит обобщающее слово (после него ставится двоеточие). Всё, что в скобках, — это пояснительные (вводные) конструкции. Не знаю, как вы отнесетесь к такой трактовке вопроса.

Comment: Ммм... менять оформление не желательно, т.к. при составлении больших списков такую конструкцию неудобно читать. Давайте я, лучше, приведу пример, где в данном случае поставлено двоеточие (Chest and Corpse locations):http://darksouls2.wikidot.com/twinkling-titanite